# php-mysql nothing is showing on the page

Tags: php, mysql

Hi the following is not sowing any thing on the webpage. Where I went wrong?

```
The following is a link to profile.php
?>
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $id;?></a>
<?PHP
```

=======================================
This is the linked php file profile.php

```
<html>

<body bgcolor='#4c5865'>

<p style="position: absolute ; top: 0; text-align: left><font face="geneva" size='1' color="#ccc"><a href="cbs.php" ><b><font color="white">Home</font></p></a>
<?php

include("db1.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];

$result = $mysql_query ("select agt,dvd FROM agttot where agt='$id'");

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
$ac =$row[0];
$dc =$row[1];
$bc =$row[2];

 //   echo "<tr bgcolor='#a9a9a9'><td align='right'>";
    print $ac;
 //   echo "</td><td align='right'><b>"; 
    print $dc;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you see no output it is likely because of a fatal error in your code. Turn on error reporting always when developing:  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: At a minimum, you _must_ call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$id` to protect your script from SQL injection. In the long run, consider switching to an API supporting prepared statements like MySQLi or PDO, as the old `mysql_*()` extension is facing deprecation.

Comment: Where are people learning to code at these days?

Comment: @keyboardsmasher certainly not reputable sources, or even official references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add `;` after `$id` in this line:

`<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $id;?></a>`

`mysql_query()` is a function (also don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they're deprecated!) so it shouldn't be called with a `$` in front here:

`$result = $mysql_query ("select agt,dvd FROM agttot where agt='$id'");`

Comment: I didnt get any idea and the changes are also not working

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping the '$id' before it gets put into your SQL.

Your mysql_query contains an extra $, before the function name:

```
$result = **$**mysql_query ("select agt,dvd FROM agttot where agt='$id'");
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query ("select agt,dvd FROM agttot where agt='$id'");
```

PS, avoid the mysql_ set of functions, they are/will be deprecated very soon. Use mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: Yeah!! finally got it. thank you. I am newbie and must be using a old methodology.

Comment: Connection sequence is saved in php file,                             <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("connection failed");
$sel=mysql_select_db('club',$con);
?>                                                                           2.my database is having records. 3.I am using mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array... I dont have any idea about mysqli_prepare and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your problem is. There are a few area in question I'd check:

1. Is `$id` set? Does it have an integer value?
2. Syntax error here:

   ```
   <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $id;?></a>
   ```

   need a semi-colon (;) column 39. (not 100% sure if needed in this case but always be sure)
3. Is there records in the database?
4. Where is the connection sequence?
5. Have you selected a database?
6. Should you still be using mySQL?

Seeing as mySQL is now depreciated here is a mySQLi example (procedural):

```
$con=new mysqli_connect('location','user','password','database');
$query=mysqli_prepare('SELECT agt,dvd FROM agttot WHERE agt=?',$con);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(, $query, 'i', intval($_GET['id']));
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$agt,$dvd);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)){
    $result[]='<tr><td>'.$agt.'</td><td>'.$dvd.'</td></tr>';
}

mysqli_stmt_close($query);
mysqli_close($con);

echo(isset($result))?$result:$_GET['id'].' < is this a valid record?';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <html>

  <body bgcolor='#4c5865'>

  <p style="position: absolute ; top: 0; text-align: left><font face="geneva" size='1' color="#ccc"><a href="cbs.php" ><b><font color="white">Home</font></p></a>
 <?php

 include("db1.php");
 $id=$_GET['id'];

$result = $mysql_query ("select agt,dvd FROM agttot where agt='$id'");

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
$ac =$row['agt'];
$dc =$row['dvd'];  // you dont have to make numbers here but the column names as it saids in your query
$bc =$row[2];    // you dont have to make numbers here but the column names as it saids in your query

//   echo "<tr bgcolor='#a9a9a9'><td align='right'>";
echo $ac.'<br />';
//   echo "</td><td align='right'><b>"; 
echo  $dc.'<br />';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```